# How to make sure teapot is safe after being on fire without water

Tags: food-safety, equipment

I left my teapot on the stove for about 30 minutes by accident. By the time I noticed, all the water had boiled out. So, I turned off the stove and let it cool.

When I went to put water in it again, black flakes began to come off the bottom of the pot on the inside, but I could not scrub out all the flakey stuff easily.

I have a stainless steel teapot. Are these flakes hazardous? How do I clean my pot to make sure it's safe to drink from again?

Comment: Actually, leaving the kettle/teapot to boil dry and then immediately fill it from the cold water tap is a way to have the limestone break, so you can rinse it out. Don't overdo this though, that would be bad for the kettle.

Comment: What counts as overdoing it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably just [limescale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limescale) stuck to the bottom of your pot that blackened. I don't think burnt limescale is harmful, but it shouldn't be too hard to remove. You can try cleaning it using standard means to remove scale from kettles, like using vinegar.

Comment: I would speculate that the black colour comes from dried tea components embedded in the limescale. With no impact on the safety aspect, though.